# How do i update a PDf "Document Properties"?

Tags: pdf, properties

How do i update a PDf "Document Properties"? Open a pdf file and right click on it and select the "Document Properties" I need to fill in the Tile, Description, Author etc., I am not able to edit the PDf properties. I have only Adobe Reader installed on mine machine.

Comment: I believe this question should be asked on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience of using this but you could try something like:

http://www.pdfpropertieschanger.com/

this seems to fit the job.

Ruth

Comment: You need to have Adobe acrobat in order to edit the Document properties. But if the document is protected from the owner then Nothing can help.